# TypeError: flatMap is not a function

Tags: node.js

I was trying to install parcel to run my own npm package but I get the following error when starting the HTML with parcel lib:

```
TypeError: [(...previousDevDepRequests.entries(...))].filter(...).flatMap is not a function
    at Object.run (C:\Users\ishantr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\parcel\node_modules\@parcel\core\lib\requests\AssetRequest.js:94:122)
```

I am on v10.16.0, and my index template is something like this:

```
<img src="xxx.jpg" alt="" class="some_class_name">
<script src="./index.js"></script>
```

It calls the js file to run some business logic.

Comment: You may need a newer Node, or to polyfill the support: https://node.green/#ES2019-features-Array-prototype--flat--flatMap-

Comment: I am on the latest node version but having the same error...

Comment: Are you using a Node version where that method is _supported_? Or, even better: which Node version _are_ you on?

Comment: I am on v10.16.0

Comment: Then why is it surprising you'd get that error, given the information in the link I provided? I'd guess Parcel have dropped support for Node 10 now it's out of LTS.

Comment: You're running node 10.16 and flatMap doesn't exist until node 11.0 - see [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap#browser_compatibility) on MDN. If it's a possibility, you should consider upgrading to node 14.x as it's the current LTS release.

Comment: good one, thanks, guys.

Answer (score 2):

you should consider upgrading to node 14.x .
it worked for me
..i was using node version 10.19.0